# Is there some WebKit alternative for Qt on Android?

Tags: android, c++, qt

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/android-support.html

Qt for android clearly say: "All Qt modules (essential and add-on) are supported except Qt WebKit, Qt NFC, Qt Serial Port"

is there some alternative for WebKit then? How would I render a web page on Qt project without WebKit? Did someone find some alternative that works on android and is compatible / support similar features?

Answer (score 1):

Qt WebEngine Technology is under development. For a Qt and cross platform solution you should wait for it to be available on Android.

Currently to incorporate web content into your Qt application on Android, you need to use a native web component. Interacting with native contents could be done by the [Qt Android Extras](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) module with a JNI convenience API.